# Windows issue on fresh Openbox

Tags: openbox

I have a fresh install of Open Box on Debian Buster (with GNOME desktop installed before, I want to switch to Open Box). I have an issue with the windows :  when I drag (or resize them) it produces this

[image]

I don't really know what information I can provide to help you solve my issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that GNOME is still installed in parallel with OpenBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a compositor, like [compton](https://github.com/chjj/compton). Compositors sometimes help with screen tear, like in your screenshot.